# SQL SELECT with m:n relationship

Tags: sql, mysql

I have m:n relationship between users and tags. One user can have m tags, and one tag can belong to n users. Tables look something like this:

```
USER:
ID
USER_NAME

USER_HAS_TAG:
USER_ID
TAG_ID

TAG:
ID
TAG_NAME
```

Let's say that I need to select all users, who have tags "apple", "orange" AND "banana". What would be the most effective way to accomplish this using SQL (MySQL DB)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the other good answers, it's also possible to check the condition in a WHERE clause:

```
select *
from user u
where 3 = (
    select count(distinct t.id)
    from user_has_tag uht
    inner join tag t on t.id = uht.tag_id
    where t.name in ('apple', 'orange', 'banana') 
    and uht.user_id = u.userid
)
```

The `count(distinct ...)` makes sure a tag is counted only once, even if the user has multiple 'banana' tags.

By the way, the site fruitoverflow.com is not yet registered :)

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  user_id
        FROM    tag t
        JOIN    user_has_tag uht
        ON      uht.tag_id = t.id
        WHERE   tag_name IN ('apple', 'orange', 'banana')
        GROUP BY
                user_id
        HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3
        ) q
JOIN    user u
ON      u.id = q.user_id
```

By removing `HAVING COUNT(*)`, you get `OR` instead of `AND` (though it will not be the most efficient way)

By replacing `3` with `2`, you get users that have exactly two of three tags defined.

By replacing `= 3` with `>= 2`, you get users that have at least two of three tags defined.

Comment: that is for sure not most efficient as will aggregate all records. E.g. if no users match criteria, much useless work will be done
3 selfjoin is the efficient way to go

Comment: `@noonex`: on a realworld data (lots of users, lots of tags, high user-tag cardinality) this is an efficient way. `tag_name IN (...)` is a sargable condition, it will aggregate only the records with the mathing tags. And what if you need to make the query match `4` or `20` tags? With self-joins, you will need to rewrite the query structure, with `GROUP BY` only the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it all with joins...

```
select u.*
from user u

inner join user_has_tag ut1 on u.id = ut1.user_id 
inner join tag t1 on ut1.tag_id = t1.id and t1.tag_name = 'apple'

inner join user_has_tag ut2 on u.id = ut2.user_id 
inner join tag t2 on ut2.tag_id = t2.id and t2.tag_name = 'orange'

inner join user_has_tag ut3 on u.id = ut3.user_id 
inner join tag t3 on ut3.tag_id = t3.id and t3.tag_name = 'banana'
```

Comment: technically more efficient way will be using appropriate tag_id and selfjoin only user_has_tag table (3 times). But approach is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM USER u
INNER JOIN USER_HAS_TAG uht
ON u.id = uht.user_id
INNER JOIN TAG t
ON uht.TAG_ID = t.ID
WHERE t.TAG_NAME IN ('apple','orange','banana')
```

Comment: This works, if you want users with tag 'apple', 'orange' OR 'banana', not all three.