# SQL query: where array is in array

Tags: sql, arrays, filtering

I've got sample data in database:

```
id (int)   name (varchar)           parts (varchar)
1          some_element             wheel, bearing, hinge, servo
2          another_element          bearing, servo, lift
3          third_element            motor, wire
```

I want to filter results by parts. For example:
I'm typing **wheel, servo** - no results

I'm typing **wheel, bearing, servo, hinge** - returns *some_element* record

I'm typing **bearing, servo, lift, wheel, bearing, hinge** - it returns *some_element* and *another_element*

How to construct SQL query? Is there any other data type better for parts field?

Comment: You need to normalize your data.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some normalization so that you can write queries more easily and won't have such anomalies.

You'll need another structure, like:

The `element` table

```
+----+---------------+
| id | name          |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | some_element  |
+----+---------------+
|  2 | another_elem  |
+----+---------------+
|  3 | third_elem    |
+----+---------------+
```

The `part` table

```
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | wheel    |
+----+----------+
|  2 | bearing  |
+----+----------+
|  3 | hinge    |
+----+----------+
|  4 | servo    |
+----+----------+
 etc..
```

And another, such as `element_parts` to connect the other two by an m:n relation

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | elem_id | part_id |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 | 1       | 1       |
+----+---------+---------+
|  2 | 1       | 2       |
+----+---------+---------+
|  3 | 1       | 3       |
+----+---------+---------+
|  4 | 2       | 3       |
+----+---------+---------+
|  5 | 2       | 4       |
+----+---------+---------+
 etc..
```

And now you can write a query to, say, filter elements that contain (or need) `wheel` and `servo` (adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680855/sql-select-with-mn-relationship) question's accepted answer):

```
select *
from element e
where 2 = (
    select count(distinct p.id)
    from element_parts ep
    inner join part p on p.id = ep.part_id
    where p.name in ('wheel', 'servo') 
    and ep.elem_id = e.id
);
```

Comment: It's so easy! Thanks :)

Comment: Well, the "easier query writing" part was a bit of a lie, of course you can do some RegEx pattern matching magic (like `LIKE`), but that's just smothering up the problem.